# Kubernetes / OpenShift send request to all pods

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have a GraphQL request that updates the cache. I have 3 pods running.
Is there a mechanism for me to trigger the cache update on all pods with a single api call making sure that cache on all pods has been refreshed

I think the Kubernets/OpenShift APIs should be at my rescue. But need some inputs

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is by calling each pod.

Usually you would achieve this by defining an Kubernetes service that includes all pods and then use the Kubernetes/OpenShift API to get the pod's IP addresses (via Kubernetes endpoints).

If you do not want to use the Kubernetes API you can also use a [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) and query the IPs via DNS.

Here is an example for a service `my-service` with two pods:

```
sh-5.1$ getent hosts my-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
10.129.3.95     my-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
10.131.11.212   my-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: I am unable to make the call
curl https://<ip address>/<api>  gets timed out

I tried this from the oc command line.

Comment: You can only call those IPs from pods inside your cluster.